# How do I get the total number of iOS devices by generation from Microsoft InTune?

Tags: microsoft-intune

I'm new to Microsoft InTune and I want to be able to determine how many iOS devices I have enrolled by generation (4th, 5th, 6th, etc). I've looked and it doesnt seem straightforward.

Comment: Can't you do that with the standard reporting features ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/reports#all-devices-report-operational  - Choose Columns to provide more device details for the report. This report provides filtering, searching, paging, and sorting capabilities

Comment: I appreciate the answer but i was looking for something that summarizes this information. Like...

iPad 5th Gen: 50
iPad 6th Gen: 12
iPad 7th Gen: 7
etc

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I could export my entire device inventory to a csv using the Export button. Once there I will aggregate the data.